# javascript message passing in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

Can anyone please help me how to do this? I would like to pass the message from the websocket to the serial port every time I receive a message

```
var firmata = require('firmata');
var board = new firmata.Board('COM4');

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8081 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(websocket) {
    websocket.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    board.servoWrite(5, message); //This doesn't work but how do i send?
}

board.on("ready", function() {
  board.servoWrite(5, 0); // this works but i need the message from above which I cant access.

});
```

Comment: I had to call board.servoConfig(5, 0, 0 ); It is a mandatory call and doesn't work without it :) thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasnt a sytax error .. Had to add

```
board.servoConfig(5, 0, 30);
```

I added it in the code like this:

```
var firmata = require('firmata');
var board = new firmata.Board('COM4',function(){

});

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8081 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(websocket) {
    websocket.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    board.servoConfig(5, 0, 30);
    board.servoWrite(5, message); //This doesn't work but how do i send?
}

board.on("ready", function() {
  board.servoWrite(5, 0); // this works but i need the message from above which I cant access.

});
```

Comment: where did you have to add this?

Comment: And what does this do?

Comment: I didn't have time to check through the documentation. I saw it in the examples and guessed that this was missing. From the brief reading it said it sets the mapping in degrees [0,30] -> [0,180] for pin 5

Answer (score 0):

You should add the listeners after `board` is ready.

```
board.on("ready", function() {
    wss.on('connection', function connection(websocket) {
        websocket.on('message', function incoming(message) {
            board.servoWrite(5, message);
        });
    });
});
```

Either that or declare a variable that tells you if it's ready.

```
var isReady = false;

board.on("ready", function() {
    isReady = true;
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(websocket) {
    websocket.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        if(isReady)
            board.servoWrite(5, message);
    });
});
```

Comment: the order  doesnt matter I think :) I figured out the problem though thank you very much :)